How do I get hydroelastic contact forces in Drake C++?
I have the following grasp simulation in Drake C++ with a Robotiq-140 gripper on a irregular mesh (which is derived from the robotiq.cc code mentioned in Issue 19842 ):
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <fmt/format.h>

#include "drake/multibody/parsing/parser.h"
#include "drake/multibody/parsing/package_map.h"
#include "drake/multibody/plant/multibody_plant.h"
#include "drake/multibody/parsing/collision_filter_groups.h"
#include "drake/systems/analysis/simulator.h"
#include "drake/systems/framework/diagram_builder.h"
#include "drake/systems/primitives/constant_vector_source.h"
#include "drake/visualization/visualization_config_functions.h"
#include "drake/multibody/plant/discrete_contact_pair.h"


namespace drake {
    namespace examples {
        namespace simple_gripper {
            namespace {

                int do_main() {
                    auto meshcat = std::make_shared<geometry::Meshcat>();
                    systems::DiagramBuilder<double> builder;

                    auto [plant, scene_graph] =
                            multibody::AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(&builder, 0.002);
                    plant.set_discrete_contact_approximation( drake::multibody::DiscreteContactApproximation::kLagged);

                    multibody::Parser parser(&plant);
                    multibody::PackageMap::RemoteParams params;
                    params.urls = {"https://github.com/RussTedrake/kinova-movo/archive/"
                                   "d94d1d7da7ff8fc71f2439bb0a8989f1e6fd79b4.tar.gz"};
                    params.sha256 =
                            "a9201477a23f410f10d00e86847de778c175d3d3c8971be52a9ac881194e4887";
                    params.strip_prefix = "kinova-movo-d94d1d7da7ff8fc71f2439bb0a8989f1e6fd79b4";
                    parser.package_map().AddRemote("kinova-movo", params);
                    parser.package_map().AddPackageXml(
                            parser.package_map().GetPath("kinova-movo") +
                            "/movo_common/movo_description/package.xml");

                    std::string with_mimic = R"""(
directives:
- add_model:
    name: spam
    file: package://drake/examples/simple_gripper/mesh.sdf
    default_free_body_pose: { base_link: {
        translation: [0.2, 0.05, 0.00],
        rotation: !Rpy { deg: [90.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]}
    } }

- add_model:
    name: table
    file: package://drake/examples/kuka_iiwa_arm/models/table/extra_heavy_duty_table_surface_only_collision.sdf

- add_weld:
    parent: world
    child: table::table_link
    X_PC:
        translation: [0.0, 0.0, -0.81]
)""";

                    parser.AddModelsFromString(with_mimic, "dmd.yaml");
                    parser.AddModelsFromUrl(
                            "package://drake/examples/simple_gripper/robotiq_140_gripper.urdf");
                    plant.WeldFrames(
                            plant.world_frame(),
                            plant.GetBodyByName("robotiq_arg2f_base_link").body_frame(),
                            math::RigidTransformd(math::RollPitchYawd(M_PI , 0, M_PI),
                                                  Eigen::Vector3d(0.2, 0, 0.21)));

                    plant.Finalize();

                    auto torque = builder.AddSystem<systems::ConstantVectorSource>(Vector1d(2));
                    builder.Connect(torque->get_output_port(), plant.get_actuation_input_port());

                    visualization::AddDefaultVisualization(&builder, meshcat);

                    auto diagram = builder.Build();

                    // Set up simulator.
                    systems::Simulator simulator(*diagram);

                    meshcat->StartRecording(32.0, false);
                    simulator.AdvanceTo(20.0);
                    meshcat->PublishRecording();

                    // Pause so that you can see the meshcat output.
                    std::cout << "[Press Ctrl-C to finish]." << std::endl;
                    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

                    return 0;
                }

            }  // namespace
        }  // namespace simple_gripper
    }  // namespace examples
}  // namespace drake

int main(int, char*[]) {
    return drake::examples::simple_gripper::do_main();
}

It produces the following contact forces:

How do I get the two long red (translational) contact forces and their starting points in the picture?

One way of doing this is to add the following to your code.
const auto& final_context = simulator.get_context();

const auto& plant_context = diagram->GetSubsystemContext(plant, final_context);

const ContactResults<double>& contact_results =
        plant.get_contact_results_output_port().Eval<ContactResults<double>>(plant_context);

std::cout << "Contact forces and centroids at the end of the simulation:" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < contact_results.num_hydroelastic_contacts(); ++i) {
    const HydroelasticContactInfo<double>& info =
            contact_results.hydroelastic_contact_info(i);

    const Vector3d& F_Ac_W = info.F_Ac_W().translational();
    const Vector3d& p_WC = info.contact_surface().centroid();

    std::cout << "Contact " << i << ":" << std::endl;
    //Force applied on body A, at the centroid point C, expressed in the world frame W
    std::cout << "  F_Ac_W: [" << F_Ac_W.x() << ", " << F_Ac_W.y() << ", " << F_Ac_W.z() << "]" << std::endl;
    //position p_WC of the centroid point C in the world frame W
    std::cout << "  p_WC: [" << p_WC.x() << ", " << p_WC.y() << ", " << p_WC.z() << "]" << std::endl;
}

(more info about this can be found here:
https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html
https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_contact_results.html
https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_hydroelastic_contact_info.html
)
You can print out the values of the contact forces at the end of the simulation. The whole code is then:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <fmt/format.h>

#include "drake/common/eigen_types.h"
#include "drake/multibody/parsing/parser.h"
#include "drake/multibody/parsing/package_map.h"
#include "drake/multibody/plant/multibody_plant.h"
#include "drake/multibody/parsing/collision_filter_groups.h"
#include "drake/systems/analysis/simulator.h"
#include "drake/systems/framework/diagram_builder.h"
#include "drake/systems/primitives/constant_vector_source.h"
#include "drake/visualization/visualization_config_functions.h"
#include "drake/multibody/plant/discrete_contact_pair.h"
#include "drake/multibody/plant/contact_results.h"

namespace drake {
    namespace examples {
        namespace simple_gripper {

            using Eigen::Vector3d;
            using multibody::ContactResults;
            using multibody::HydroelasticContactInfo;
            namespace {

                int do_main() {
                    auto meshcat = std::make_shared<geometry::Meshcat>();
                    systems::DiagramBuilder<double> builder;

                    auto [plant, scene_graph] =
                            multibody::AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(&builder, 0.002);
                    plant.set_discrete_contact_approximation( drake::multibody::DiscreteContactApproximation::kLagged);

                    multibody::Parser parser(&plant);
                    multibody::PackageMap::RemoteParams params;
                    params.urls = {"https://github.com/RussTedrake/kinova-movo/archive/"
                                   "d94d1d7da7ff8fc71f2439bb0a8989f1e6fd79b4.tar.gz"};
                    params.sha256 =
                            "a9201477a23f410f10d00e86847de778c175d3d3c8971be52a9ac881194e4887";
                    params.strip_prefix = "kinova-movo-d94d1d7da7ff8fc71f2439bb0a8989f1e6fd79b4";
                    parser.package_map().AddRemote("kinova-movo", params);
                    parser.package_map().AddPackageXml(
                            parser.package_map().GetPath("kinova-movo") +
                            "/movo_common/movo_description/package.xml");

                    std::string with_mimic = R"""(
directives:
- add_model:
    name: spam
    file: package://drake/examples/simple_gripper/mesh.sdf
    default_free_body_pose: { base_link: {
        translation: [0.2, 0.05, 0.00],
        rotation: !Rpy { deg: [90.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]}
    } }

- add_model:
    name: table
    file: package://drake/examples/kuka_iiwa_arm/models/table/extra_heavy_duty_table_surface_only_collision.sdf

- add_weld:
    parent: world
    child: table::table_link
    X_PC:
        translation: [0.0, 0.0, -0.81]
)""";

                    parser.AddModelsFromString(with_mimic, "dmd.yaml");
                    parser.AddModelsFromUrl(
                            "package://drake/examples/simple_gripper/robotiq_140_gripper.urdf");
                    plant.WeldFrames(
                            plant.world_frame(),
                            plant.GetBodyByName("robotiq_arg2f_base_link").body_frame(),
                            math::RigidTransformd(math::RollPitchYawd(M_PI , 0, M_PI),
                                                  Eigen::Vector3d(0.2, 0, 0.21)));

                    plant.Finalize();

                    auto torque = builder.AddSystem<systems::ConstantVectorSource>(Vector1d(2));
                    builder.Connect(torque->get_output_port(), plant.get_actuation_input_port());

                    visualization::AddDefaultVisualization(&builder, meshcat);

                    auto diagram = builder.Build();

                    // Set up simulator.
                    systems::Simulator simulator(*diagram);

                    meshcat->StartRecording(32.0, false);
                    simulator.AdvanceTo(20.0);
                    meshcat->PublishRecording();

                    const auto& final_context = simulator.get_context();

                    const auto& plant_context = diagram->GetSubsystemContext(plant, final_context);

                    const ContactResults<double>& contact_results =
                            plant.get_contact_results_output_port().Eval<ContactResults<double>>(plant_context);

                    std::cout << "Contact forces and centroids at the end of the simulation:" << std::endl;
                    for (int i = 0; i < contact_results.num_hydroelastic_contacts(); ++i) {
                        const HydroelasticContactInfo<double>& info =
                                contact_results.hydroelastic_contact_info(i);

                        const Vector3d& F_Ac_W = info.F_Ac_W().translational();
                        const Vector3d& p_WC = info.contact_surface().centroid();

                        std::cout << "Contact " << i << ":" << std::endl;
                        //Force applied on body A, at the centroid point C, expressed in the world frame W
                        std::cout << "  F_Ac_W: [" << F_Ac_W.x() << ", " << F_Ac_W.y() << ", " << F_Ac_W.z() << "]" << std::endl;
                        //position p_WC of the centroid point C in the world frame W
                        std::cout << "  p_WC: [" << p_WC.x() << ", " << p_WC.y() << ", " << p_WC.z() << "]" << std::endl;
                    }


                    // Pause so that you can see the meshcat output.
                    std::cout << "[Press Ctrl-C to finish]." << std::endl;
                    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

                    return 0;
                }

            }  // namespace
        }  // namespace simple_gripper
    }  // namespace examples
}  // namespace drake

int main(int, char*[]) {
    return drake::examples::simple_gripper::do_main();
}

The output would look like this:
Contact forces and centroids at the end of the simulation:
Contact 0:
  F_Ac_W: [0.000115463, -0.0332584, 2.36681]
  p_WC: [0.22126, 0.0196855, -0.0459446]
Contact 1:
  F_Ac_W: [-0.0887268, 10.3418, -0.539927]
  p_WC: [0.201652, -0.0288424, -0.0140817]
Contact 2:
  F_Ac_W: [0.0886113, -10.3086, -1.33639]
  p_WC: [0.200856, 0.0288451, -0.0139309]

Steps to reproduce and run this code and example
git clone -b VanillaDrakeWithIssue19842Mods https://github.com/hedaniel7/drake.git
cd drake
git checkout aabad5f8c1599d8507331e668c634e5666466cda
bazel build //examples/simple_gripper:robotiq_140_shape_completion_get_contact_forces
bazel run //examples/simple_gripper:robotiq_140_shape_completion_get_contact_forces



It's also worth noting that depending on how your scene is configured, the contact results point contacts will also be populated (i.e., if two rigid hydroelastic geometries touch). So, unless you're confident that all of the contacts are hydroelastic, it might be worth looking there as well.
